# UInavigationcontroller pop: it leaves the content of the popped view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

The situation:
I have an application entirely based on UInavigationcontroller.
At some point in the application I push the controller A wich contains several subviews.
Then i push a controller B which is an other new instance of the same class of controller A. Also controller B has some subviews.

When I pop controller B, the view associated to the controller A is shown. 
The problem is that on the screen there are also all the things of the view associated to controller B (over the subviews of A).

My guess is that somehow the problem is related to the fact that both controllers are instances of the same class. (With controller of different classes it works perfectly)

Thx.

**Edit:** All the stuff is done programmatically and with xib (no storyboard)

Push of view A:

```
ScreenViewController *secondView = [[ScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenViewController" bundle:nil];

// set some properties

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

Push of view B:

```
ScreenViewController *newScreenView = [[ScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenViewController" bundle:nil];

// set some properties

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newScreenView animated:YES];
```

The view associated to the `ScreenViewController` contains a `UIView` (as a property) to wich I add all the subview that I need to display. I use a property and not directly the view because I need to put it into a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: More information required... post some code, maybe a storyboard pic...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using some code similar to:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:mySubview];
```

I've dealt with this before by removing the subviews when the view is about to disappear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^(void){

                         mySubview.alpha = 0;

                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [mySubview removeFromSuperview];


      }];
    }
```

The above code will execute when you push or pop a new view controller, and it will 'fade out' the subview. When it's done, it removes it from the view. You just have to make sure that the subview gets re-added every time the view loads again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually the structure is a bit more complicated since to the view associated to `ScreenViewController` I put an instance of `UIScrollView` and on it I put an other view (used in order to allow zooming). To this one I add all the subviews that I need to show.

Comment: @Lando In that case, you can just use this code and replace the subview of the scrollview with the scrollview itself.

Comment: A question: why do you set the alpha to 0?

Comment: It's purely for animation so the view 'fades' out before it gets removed. If you don't need the animation, you can simply `[mySubview removeFromSuperview];` in viewWillDisappear.

Comment: That block of code will animate the 'alpha' of the subview to zero over a period of 0.3 seconds, and when it's done, remove the subview.